# Scikit learn multilayer neural network

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

As per the documentation provided by Scikit learn

```
hidden_layer_sizes : tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default (100,)
```

I have little doubt.

In my code what I have configured is

```
MLPClassifier(algorithm='l-bfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
```

so what does `5` and `2` indicates?

What I understand is, 5 is the numbers of hidden layers, but then what is 2?

Ref - http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#

Answer (score 8):

From [the link you provided](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#), in parameter table, `hidden_layer_sizes` row:

> The ith element represents the number of neurons in the ith hidden
>   layer

Which means that you will have `len(hidden_layer_sizes)` **hidden** layers, and, each hidden layer `i` will have `hidden_layer_sizes[i]` neurons.

In your case, `(5, 2)` means:

- 1rst hidden layer has 5 neurons
- 2nd hidden layer has 2 neurons

So the number of hidden layers is implicitely set

Answer (score 0):

*Some details that I found online concerning the architecture and the units of the input, hidden and output layers in **sklearn**.*

- The number of input units will be the number of features
- For multiclass classification the number of output units will be the number of labels
- Try a single hidden layer, or if more than one then each hidden layer should have the same number of units
- The more units in a hidden layer the better, try the same as the number of input features up to twice or even three or four times that